# Sensor for tyre direcction

Tags: sensor, automotive, proximity-sensor

I am new to driving and get difficulty in knowing Tyre direction if they straight, or turned left or right, I think a sensor connected to my smartphone probably will do the trick of telling me direction tires are directed. Which sensor do you think would fit this problem?

I was thinking me be one sensor on fixed platform on car,one on Tyre rim  and one on axle so that  kind of  right angles triangle is formed.

I am looking for direction of tyre when car parked not driving

Comment: Related question on another Stack Exchange site: [Read steering angle data in real time](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/17634/read-steering-angle-data-in-real-time).

Comment: The last thing you want to be doing while driving is looking at your smartphone ... If you want to know if your tyres are pointing straight ahead - look at the direction your car is going. If it's going straight then the tyres are pointed straight.

Comment: It would help if you tell us what you are trying to accomplish. As it currently stands, there is not anywhere near enough information in your question for anyone to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: pull the car into an empty parking-lot (hundreds of empty parking spaces), and learn how the car's motion correlates with the steering wheel. To be a safe driver, this "understanding" must become inherent to you. So---go find an empty parking, get the car moving at about 5 kilometers/hour, and start turning the steering wheel.

Comment: The steering wheel position should give a good indication of wheel position, at least when the wheels are near "straight ahead".  To drive safely, you need to instinctively feel the wheel position - you shouldn't need to depend on electronic aids. (People were driving cars long before smartphones were invented.)

Comment: If you are looking at instrumentation for the output of a sensor to detect the wheel position you are going to crash your car.

Comment: Your question is one of the top 20 crazy in a bad way ideas that i have seen.

Comment: Caught my flabbergasted reflection in the monitor. Still laughing. The smartphone generation strikes again.

Answer (score 2):

Your car already has that sensor.

Plug in one of those bluetooth OBD-II (on-board diagnostics) modules, and read the steering wheel angle.